# `af` vs `afr` in Radare2

Tags: radare2

I am trying to understand the difference between `analyze functions` and `analyze functions recursively` in Radare2. Given a code snippet like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void b() {
    printf("b is called\n");
}

void a() {
   printf("a is called\n");
   b();
}


int main() {
    a();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run `afr` on the main function, it finds the following functions:

```
0x0000066a    1 21           main
0x0000064d    1 29           sym.a
0x00000510    1 6            sym.imp.puts
0x0000063a    1 19           sym.b
```

However, when I run `af` on the main function, it again finds the same functions:

```
0x0000066a    1 21           main
0x0000064d    1 29           sym.a
0x00000510    1 6            sym.imp.puts
0x0000063a    1 19           sym.b
```

I have not changed the default value of `anal.calls` which is set to `false`

So, my question is what extra is `afr` finding that `af` isn't?

I am using Radare2 version 5.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`af` and `afr` are different. Check radare's code base for deep understanding - https://github.com/radareorg/radare2/blob/8d678888a97d9aed4049d1a7467132c41ad6ffa7/libr/core/cmd_anal.c.

[image]

[image]

Now, consider following example to understand how they differ.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int one()
{
return 1;
}

int fact(int n) {
   if (n==0)
      return 1;
   else if (n==1)
      return one();
   else
      return n*fact(n-1);
}

int main(void) {
      return fact(5);
}
```

I just used [this](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Ecs573/fall2002/notes/lec273/lecture16/16_3.htm) factorial code and modified it a little. And following is the radare2 output.

```
$ radare2 a.out
 -- This page intentionally left blank.
[0x00401020]> afl
[0x00401020]> s main
[0x0040114e]> afl
[0x0040114e]> af main
[0x0040114e]> afl
0x0040114e    1 16           main
0x00401111    6 61           sym.fact
[0x0040114e]> afr main
[0x0040114e]> afl
0x0040114e    1 16           main
0x00401111    6 61           sym.fact
0x00401106    1 11           sym.one
```

Note the detection of additional function when recursive analysis is used.

Comment: I am still now sure why my code isn't able to produce different results.

Comment: R is for recursive your function is not recursive a recursive function is function that calls itself until it is stopped by an external condition. Like in the answer above fact (n) calls itself until n is 1 so if n is 10 fact will be calked 9 times like main fact10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 return to main